# Unable to access global variable entire one controller in sencha

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

I have been trying to access global value inside one controller, but could not access it. i have been following this [How to define global variable in sencha](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18095037/how-to-define-global-variable-in-sencha) but could not set and access global values.

**in Controller**

```
config: {
    successMessage:100,
    control: {
      'submitnewword': {
         activate: 'onActivate',
         itemtap: 'onItemTap',
         ConfirmTestCommand:'Confirm'
        },
    .......
   },
  onSearchKeyUp: function(searchField) {
    success: function (response) {
       this.setSuccessMessage(1);
   }
   else {
     this.setSuccessMessage(0);
   }   
}

and access it

Confirm: function () {
   console.log("Confirm----- Caling on Controller");
   var testing=this.getSuccessMessage();
   console.log("Confirm----- value--"+testing);         
},
```

I dont know, what is the wrong with my code.

I am getting this on console:

> Uncaught TypeError: Object [object global] has no method
>   'setSuccessMessage'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is about scope and you can solve it by:

In your controller init method

```
init : function() {
   me = this;
}
```

Now access the methods using

```
   me.setSuccessMessage(1)

   me.getSuccessMessage();
```

Comment: can we do it same in view i have been trying it but unable to access global value change it's value depending upon action.

Comment: @sur007 yes, you can do it but within initialize.

Comment: i am getting error on it. I did as you mentioned in above answer. you mean not in init

Comment: OK, error has been diminished but value doesnot change. What can i do for that?

Comment: can you look onto this then http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18464355/unable-to-change-the-value-of-variable-in-button-click-sencha

Answer (score 0):

I think you ran onto the scope visibility issue... I'm not sure where an exception is emitted, from onSearchKeyUp() or from Confirm(). But guess inside it this points not to the controller instance. To help you more you need share more info (sources)

Answer (score 0):

The `success` function inside `onSearchKeyUp` has a different scope when it is called. So, inside it, `this` is not your controller where the `successMessage` (and of course, its getter and setter) is defined.

A solution is to "bind" the `success` function to the controller scope using:

```
success: Ext.bind(function (response) {
       this.setSuccessMessage(1);
}, this);
```