# Unable to change the value of variable in button click - Sencha

Tags: sencha-touch-2, global-variables

I am trying to change value of variable and i did as instruction in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18459564/unable-to-access-global-varibale-entire-one-controller-in-sencha/18461874#comment27136027_18461874) post but value does not changes.

My codes are as follow:

```
Ext.define('MyApp.view.OnlineOffline', {
extend: 'Ext.Panel',  
alias: "widget.onlineoffline", 

config: {    
onlineStatus: 0,
items: [
{
xtype: 'container',
layout: 'hbox',     
cls: 'offline-wrap',
items:[
{

xtype: 'image',
cls: 'offlineCheck',
id:'onlineButton',      
width: 85,      
height:20,      
listeners: {
tap: function (button) 
{
var me = button.up('onlineoffline')
if (!Ext.device.Connection.isOnline()) 
{
 Ext.Msg.alert('Please connect to <br/>working internet Connection?');
 this.element.removeCls('onlineCheck');
 this.element.addCls('offlineCheck');
 me.setonlineStatus(1);
 } 
 else {
if(me.getOnlineStatus())
{  
console.log( 'connection yes if' + me.getOnlineStatus());                   
me.setOnlineStatus(1);
this.element.removeCls('onlineCheck');
this.element.addCls('offlineCheck');
}
else{
this.element.removeCls('offlineCheck');
this.element.addCls('onlineCheck'); 
me.setOnlineStatus(0);
console.log( 'connection yes else' + me.getOnlineStatus());                                      
} 
}
}
}
},          
]
}]
}
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple things here...

First, you are initializing `me` as a global variable, which is a bad idea.  Rather than doing this, get a reference to what you have as `me` using the button:

```
listeners: {
    tap: function (button) {
        var me = button.up('onlineoffline')
        ...
```

The problem you are having is caused because you're calling the wrong function.  Your `config` parameter is defined as `onlineStatus`, but you are calling `setonlinestatus()`.  Call `me.setOnlineStatus()` instead.  The camel-casing for the generated getters and setters will be done exactly as your `config` param, except the first letter will be capitalized.

Comment: I did as you said but value does not changes. in button tap condition only goes to else not to if.

Comment: In your `if` statement, you still need to use `me.getOnlineStatus()`, as `me.onlineStatus` will not work.

Comment: done but no change in value. It consoles connection yes else0

Comment: What do you mean it does not change?  Your initial `config` sets `onlineStatus` to `0`, so it will hit the `else` statement.  Then, you are doing `me.setOnlineStatus(0);` right before that console statement and it is printing 0, the value that you set right before it.  Are you meaning to change it to `1` there?

Comment: I mean at first the value is 0, when button clicks it should be 1 and vice versa. Yeah your help made me learn new thing today.

Comment: how can change the value to one as you said.